# Optimization of a complicated query (which uses a pagination)

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, slick, akka-stream

Suppose there are `N` tables in some database (PostgreSQL). Each table `Ti` contains the fields `(time, label)`, Where `time` is some number (for example long `timestamp`). The `label` is some text.

There are `N` conditions. Each condition `Ci` is applied to particular table `Ti`. Each condition can be complicated (uses own sub-queries, joins also).

I need to collect records from all tables `T` with conditions and get a page of sorted result. This task is solved by `SQL` and `UNION ALL`. The following pseudo illustrates fetching some page:

```
(SELECT time, label FROM T1 WHERE C1
UNION ALL
SELECT time, label FROM T2 WHERE C2
UNION ALL
...
SELECT time, label FROM Tn WHERE Cn) 
  ORDER BY time LIMIT = x OFFSET = y
  DISTINCT
```

If conditions `C` are complicated and the tables contain a large number of records then the above query is very huge and slow.
I want to split this complicated query to sub-queries, where each sub-query `Qi` is applied to a corresponding table `Ti`. In this case each sub-query is executed faster, but the problem connected with union results, sorting an pagination raises.

For this I'm going to use `akka-streams` and `slick-streaming`. The following pseudo code illustrates fetching some page for two tables:

```
  val streamT1 = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(Q1.sortBy(time)))
  val streamT2 = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(Q2.sortBy(time)))

  val pageContent = streamT1.mergeSorted(streamT2)
                            .grouped(pageSize).drop(pageNumber)
                            .runWith(Sink.headOption)
```

The following example illustrates pagination for two tables:

```
val srcT1 = Source(
    (0, "A_a"),
    (1, "A_b"),
    (2, "A_c"),
    (5, "A_d"),
    (7, "A_e"),
    (8, "A_f"),
    (9, "A_g"),
    (10, "A_h"),
    (11, "A_i"),
    (15, "A_j"),
    (16, "A_k"),
    (17, "A_l"),
    (20, "A_m"),
    ...
  )

  val srcT2 = Source(
    (3, "B_d"),
    (12, "B_e"),
    (18, "B_f"),
    ...
  )
```

The graph of timeline for the above collections is the following:

```
0     1     2                 5           7     8     9     10    11                      15    16    17                20                                                       
|     |     |                 |           |     |     |     |     |                       |     |     |                 |                                                        
A_a---A_b---A_c---------------A_d---------A_e---A_f---A_g---A_h---A_i---------------------A_j---A_k---A_l---------------A_m--->

                  3                                                     12                                  18                                                                   
                  |                                                     |                                   |                                                                    
------------------B_d---------------------------------------------------B_e---------------------------------B_f--------------->
```

Pages with `page-size=4` and sorted by `time`:

```
[A_a,A_b,A_c,B_d]   [A_d,A_e,A_f,A_g]   [A_h,A_i,B_e,A_j]   [A_k,A_l,B_f,A_m]
```

It works, but perhaps a more effective solution exists. Will be grateful if you point to the right direction.

Comment: A question perhaps better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Another point is, that there is nothing stopping you to ask all queries async (it will probably be faster than asking them sequentially) but you still will be bottlenecked by your db performace

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use the `unionAll` operation in Slick?

```
val streamT1 = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(
      (Q1 unionAll Q2 unionAll Qn).sortBy(time) ))
```

Cf: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#unions

Also, better to use the drop()/take() directly in Slick as well :

```
val streamT1 = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(
      (Q1 unionAll Q2 unionAll Qn)
        .sortBy(time)
        .drop(pageSize*pageNumber).take(pageSize) ))
```